The parameters and the number of events obtained in the GA4 real-time report are inconsistent
I use GTM to send events to my GA4, but in my real-time report, the number of events is not the same as the number of parameters below .
I use GTM to send events to my GA4 with parameters: section_id and section_name. Then I added an extra parameter to the event, debug_mode, and set it to true. This way I can see my customers' browsing information in the GA4 debug_view.   In fact, I got all the browsing information, but when I wanted to see the real-time report, there were 736 events, but there were very few parameters below.  What is the reason for this, is it because of the delay? But I actually waited two hours, and it never equaled [enter image description here]enter image description here(https://i.sstatic.net/qLx8E.png)
By the way, I have to mention that it may have something to do with the amount of events written, I have 10,000 events every 30 minutes.
On top of that, I'd like to know that it's not used in my code.But why is my GA4 still able to read events from my website?
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-xxx');
</script>


In fact, it's the latency problem, and when I wake up the next day, I find that the data has been successfully lying in my report
